# VS Code Python turtle

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, python-turtle

I need to use turtle library in Python in VS code. When I try to run my code:

```
import turtle


turtle.forward(100)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(100)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(100)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(100)
```

Terminal:

```
turtle.forward(100)
AttributeError: module 'turtle' has no attribute 'forward'
```

I found that VS code is not so popular IDE for turtle in Python, but is there any solution?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You issue is that you are not initializing a turtle. You are trying to move the module.

This is how you initialize a turtle:

```
new_turtle = turtle.Turtle()
```

Applying this to your code should look like the following:

```
import turtle

new_turtle = turtle.Turtle() 
new_turtle.forward(100)
new_turtle.left(90)
new_turtle.forward(100)
new_turtle.left(90)
new_turtle.forward(100)
new_turtle.left(90)
new_turtle.forward(100)
```

Let me know if this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
from turtle import Turtle

turtle = Turtle()


turtle.forward(100)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(100)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(100)
turtle.left(90)
turtle.forward(100)
```

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, 
a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading.
From [answer]: _"Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."_
Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score -1):

I have VS Code, and works this code.
Try it to chose interpreter path, or update turtle, or install extention for python in VSCode, or reinstall Python.
I hope I could help
Good luck